# How to put 2 char arrays in int putenv(char *string); in C

Tags: c, path

I am trying to set a variable name and variable value in the environment of Windows by using this function

```
void env_add(char varname[], char varvalue[]) {

}
```

The problem is that i do not know how to put both of these variables to `int putenv(char *string);`

Should I combine them into one char array or not?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should combine them into a single string. The string has the form *"name=value"*.

```
char* buffer = (char*) malloc( strlen(name) + 1 + strlen(value) + 1 );

strcpy( buffer, name );
strcat( buffer, "=" );
strcat( buffer, value );

putenv( buffer );

free( buffer );
```

Comment: Can you please show me an example of merging char arrays because i tried with some loops to put both arrays into a third one with no effect as it has to contain the  '=' sign between the variable name and the variable value

Comment: @user1031654: Just edited my answer to include an example of how you would do it.

Comment: It gives me this error message: void*_cdeclmalloc(size_t_Size)
Error: a value of type "void*" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char*"

Comment: @user1031654: So you are doing C++, not C. Simply cast the result of `malloc` to `char*`.

Comment: @user1031654: If your file has a *.c* extension VS2010 will compile it as C, and that error won't show since in C `void` pointers are implicitly converted to any other type of pointer.

Comment: if you mean the file that contains this functions has a .cpp extension

Comment: @user1031654: If the file has a *.cpp* extension MSVC will compile it as **C++**. If you want your code to be compiled as **C** give it a *.c* extension (or go through the compilation properties).

Comment: in the compilation properties the compiler is common for C/C++ it has only this option :/

Comment: Is there any way to do it without the malloc? With for loops and etc?

Comment: @user1031654: Then just change its extension to *.c*. Why would you want to lie to everyone -including the compiler- telling its a C++ source file?

Comment: @user1031654: Without the malloc, you would have an upper limit on the produced string length (and you don't want that). It's possible to do it with for loops and such, that's just how the implementations of `strcpy` and `strcat` do it.

Comment: I finally managed to fix it through some properties for the compiler of VS ty a lot for your help m8!